# Editing while reviewing First Post: unexpected transition to Suggested Edit reviews

Tags: support, review, suggested-edits

Just now, I was reviewing First Posts.

I came upon [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/555708/43351), which had an integral rendered as an image instead of using MathJax. I clicked edit, and there happened to be a suggested edit addressing this. I improved upon that edit, and saved.

Much to my surprise, I didn't return to the First Posts queue. Instead, I was presented the next suggested edit. This behaviour is unexpected, seeing as I was editing from the First Post queue.

First of all, I might not be finished with the First Post, and it's not showing among my activity feeds, because editing was the first thing I did. Also, the review didn't count towards the First Posts count (for I didn't "finish" it by clicking "I'm done") -- not terribly important, but it's probably good to fix that along the way.

---

This is not the first time I encountered the behaviour, so I decided to post on meta. Can something be done about this undesirable transition?

Comment: So, Lard_Farin, did you not consider any of the answers as useful to yourself or potentially to anyone?

Answer (score 1):

I replayed the scenario you describe in my dev environment. One crucial point you've missed is that as soon as you click the `edit (1)` link of the question in the first posts queue you're already redirected to the suggested edit queue. Thus accepting the suggested edit is performed in the suggested edit queue (and not in the first posts queue). After that, you simply get another suggested edit for review.

Currently there is no inline suggested edit approval inside the first posts queue. If you really want something like this write up a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) on [meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com).

Perhaps a suitable solution would be to just open up the suggested edits queue in a new window /tab when the `edit` button on a post with a suggested edit is clicked.

Comment: This is reflective of a general problem that shows up in many places: the workflow that someone would actually have when looking at a post is not always possible from the review system. I would expect that reviewing a question may require any combination of editing it, voting up or down, voting to close, and leaving a comment. But it is often necessary to leave the review system to accomplish one or more of these - which means that the review system has failed to accurately reflect what needs to be done during the review.

Answer (score 0):

This has happened to me as well. As there is no suggestion as to what to do as a workaround in the meantime I thought I'd suggest what I now do in this circumstance. Leave a short comment that suggests the OP needs to be fixed and why. Click "I'm Done". Then go to the post itself and do the edit.